# How to use async in MainPage() (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem on loading data in my Xamarin Forms app.
I call async functions in MainPage() function and i want to bind data after execution.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadThingSpeak().ContinueWith(async (t) => await GetLocation(t.Result).ContinueWith(async (r) => await LoadForecast())).GetAwaiter();
    BindingContext = bindingData;
}
```

but `BindingContext = bindingData` is execute before async functions end and is empty.

Can someone help me?

Comment: don't make async call in the constructor - try doing them from OnAppearing insetad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid making async calls in your constructor.

Instead use an async event handler and await the desired functions before setting binding context

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage {

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Appearing += onAppearing;
    }

    private async void onAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            var thingSpeakResult = await LoadThingSpeak();
            await GetLocation(thingSpeakResult);
            await LoadForecast();
            BindingContext = bindingData;
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            //handler error (Log?)
        }
    }

    //...
}
```